# formatting of the diff output

Tags: linux, shell, diff

I have 2 files that I want to differ. File B is produced appending some new line to file A.
I want to highlight the appended data by using `diff`.

I would like to avoid printing out the '>' characters and the '10a11,14' of the output below.

Reading the man pages of `diff` I can see that you can specify the formatting of the result ( LFMT ) but I am struggling in producing something useful.

Could you help in removing those characters I don't need?

Regards

AFG

```
   diff --left-column A.txt  B.txt

   10a11,14
   > TXT :   some text
   >         some text
   >         some text
   >         some text
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two easy ways of doing this, you can either parse the output of `diff` or you can use `comm`.

- `diff fileA fileB | grep '>' | sed 's/> *//'`
- `comm -13 fileA fileB`

Comment: `diff` also handles the `-u` (unidiff) format, it is easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 4):

Although more typing than just using `comm`, the following provides a demonstration of the `--GTYPE-group-format` options:

```
diff --unchanged-group-format="" --new-group-format="%>" A.txt B.txt
```

This commmand would only print those lines in `B.txt` and not in `A.txt`. The first option suppresses common lines. There's no need to use `--changed-group-format` (no lines that have different values in each file) or `--old-group-format` (everything in `A.txt` is also in `B.txt`).